# Add extra column from MySQL subquery to query result

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

So I have the following SQL query, which should return all items in the `Film` table, sorted by how many tags they have in common with the film that has `filmid=2` :

```sql
SET @id = 2;
SELECT * FROM Films
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT at1.filmid,
            Count(at1.tagid) AS common_tag_count
     FROM Taggings AS at1
     INNER JOIN Taggings AS at2 ON at1.tagid = at2.tagid
     WHERE at2.filmid = @id
     GROUP BY at1.filmid
     HAVING at1.filmid != @id
     ORDER BY common_tag_count DESC)
```

The subquery works fine by itself, but it returns two columns (`filmid` and `common_tag_count`), which means it causes a predictable "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error.

However I don't want to make the subquery only return the `filmid` column, I want to add the `common_tag_count` column to the final result of the query. Is this possible?

Comment: Rewrite as a Common Table Express (CTE)

Comment: Yes, Join the subquery instead of putting it in an IN clause

Comment: In general I recommend always using JOIN instead of `IN (subquery)`. MySQL will often optimize it better.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the count as an inline view, and do a join to the Films table. Something like this

```
SELECT f.*
     , c.common_tag_count
  FROM Films f
  JOIN ( -- inline view/derived table
         SELECT at1.filmid
              , COUNT(at1.tagid) AS common_tag_count
           FROM Taggings at1
           JOIN Taggings at2
             ON at2.tagid = at1.tagid
          WHERE at2.filmid   = @id
          GROUP
             BY at1.filmid
         HAVING at1.filmid  != @id
       ) c
    ON c.filmid = f.id   
 ORDER 
    BY c.common_tag_count DESC
     , f.id
```